# Determining if (3) is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

As far as I can tell, the tools I have for determining if an ideal I of a ring R is maximal is either: Determine another ideal it is contained within, or look at the quotient ring $R/I$ and determine if it is a field.

I have attempted the first without any success, as my only result was the ideal $(\sqrt{7})$, which, as near as I can tell, is equal to R. The second method, I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

$$(\sqrt{7}-1)(\sqrt{7}+1)\in\langle3\rangle$$

Comment: I think I'm missing something here: So far I've been able to follow your arguments and statements, but I am not sure how any of these help me solve the problem. Is this proving that the ideal is a subset of some other ideal, or does it use a definition of maximal ideal that I didn't write in my original question? I was only introduced to the concept of rings a week ago, so I am a bit lost still.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I think I see it. Since at least one element has a zero divisor, $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ cannot be a domain, and therefore not a field. Am I getting that right?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, a maximal ideal is always a prime ideal, and for a prime ideal, if $ab\in I$, then $a\in I$ or $b\in I$. Neither of $\sqrt 7\pm 1$ is a multiple of $3$.